# Negative loss values - Seq2seq model Keras

Tags: keras, loss-function, seq2seq

I'm trying to build a chatbot using the seq2seq model in Keras. I have used the standard seq2seq model specified in the Keras Blog. I have used Word2vec for word embeddings. My problem is that I am getting negative values for loss while training.
Why is this happening and how can I fix it ? Thanks.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense

# Define an input sequence and process it.
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the 
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: did you find the reason?

Comment: @Kamal - Unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: I found the reason of the negative values.
mainly because the vector representation from word2vec contains negative values so the loss function does not calculate the loss correctly
what I did was changing the decoder_target_data to be one hot encoder of all the words in the word2vec model vocabulary

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason of the negative values.
mainly because the vector representation from word2vec contains negative values so the loss function does not calculate the loss correctly

Instead of using the vector representation in the decoder_target_data, use one hot encoder of the vocabulary of all the words in the word2vec model